# JQgrid json date format

Tags: date, jqgrid, format

I have a date that is passed into my JQGrid via a Json string and it looks like

```
"31/10/2011"
```

I cannot work out the formatting via the JQGrid [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3apredefined_formatter). I just want it to appear and then be sortable in the grid.

If I post without formatting, the date looks fine but is not recognised as a date, thus the sorting is all wrong.

If I add the following date formatting to the column

```
formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { newformat: 'd/m/Y'}
```

I am getting a date back that looks like this

```
03/10/2031
```

I cannot for the life of me work out what the problem is please help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: 'd/m/Y', newformat: 'd/m/Y'}
```

sorted the problem

Comment: default format of input data is [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) like `2011-10-31` or `2011-10-31T00:00Z`. If you can make changes on the server side I would recommend you to change the format which produce your server.

Comment: @Oleg thanks for your suggestion but I am using the format as stated for a specific reason, and feel that the solution above is more cost effective when it comes to my time than changing the server side code. Thanks for your reply.