# How to change date format in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

I have one issue related to jqgrid. I have date shown in jqgrid table like "FRI MAY 17 00:00:00 IST 2013" .I want to change its format to "17/5/2013".how i can do it?

```
{name:'checkin', index:'checkin', width:60, searchoptions:{sopt:['eq']}},
```

this is my code.

Comment: What is the **input** format of the data which you use to fill the grid? Recommended source format is `ISO8601Short` ("Y-m-d" like "2013-05-18") or `ISO8601Long` ("Y-m-d H:i:s" like "2013-05-18 14:13:53")

Comment: @Oleg : I am using input fomat as date.

Comment: My question was **which input format you use**?. You wrote only in which format you **shown** the date, but not in which format you fill the data for the grid. Do you use `datatype: "local"` and fill the data in your JavaScript code or you use `datatype: "json"` (or "xml") and returns data from the server?

Comment: @Oleg: oh sorry for mistake. I have used datatype : "json".

Comment: which input format for data you use?

Comment: @Oleg: I am sending date object as "String"(i.e.milliseconds) from server and in JavaScript code I am using `datatype: "json"`

Comment: @Oleg: My date is like "FRI MAY 17 00:00:00 IST 2013" ,where "IST" is "TimeZone",but I dont know what is its source format.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try these:

```
formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: 'd/m/Y', newformat: 'd/m/Y'}
```

Given here: [JQgrid json date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10619570/jqgrid-json-date-format)

Comment: if that is the case how to change this format `2014-06-11 10:06:41.0` to `11/06/2014 10:06:41` in JqGrid ? Please help.. Thanks

Comment: please check it this link http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:predefined_formatter

Answer (score 0):

Try this!!!

```
{name:'checkin', index:'checkin', width:60, formatter: 'date', 
     formatoptions: { newformat: 'd/m/Y'}, 
     searchoptions:{sopt:['eq']}},
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: 'l, F d, Y', newformat: 'd/m/Y'}
```